# Websocket C++ implementation

Tags: c++, websocket

I already have mine Framework to deal with  I/O Socket. Is there any library that implement websocket [RCF 6445] only?
uwebsockets and websocketpp don't work for me, since they encapsulate websocket as a server, but not libary. It means that it's not a pure websocket implementation and can't accpet buffer/char * as inputstream

Comment: You can probably use this [one-file C library for WebSocket message parsing and formatting](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/751d726383b21ac58e5e28df129ba8dc8e8e8b0c/lib/facil/http/parsers/websocket_parser.h). It's part of the facil.io framework. You'll just have to adjust the code for C++ (there's some compound literals and `void *` pointer which should raise errors in C++ but are perfectly legal in C) (I'm biased, you might want to choose something else).

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a software library or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Please, visit [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for details.